# Different Google sign in pop up between headless & normal chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm facing an issue with Headless chrome.

My login screen has a button "Login via google"

When I click this button in normal mode, the below is showed:

[image]

But when I run with Headless mode, below popup is showed instead:

[image]

(The language here is Vietnamese, I think it's not related to the issue)

I have no solution for this one. Thank you!

Comment: try to modify the footprint more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591016/10413416

Comment: @Infern0: thank you very much! It is okay now!